# How to call webservices from background in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am making one application in which one webservices need to  be called, is it possible to call webservices related to JSON in background,when user press homebutton in iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call asynchronous request using

```
NSMutableURLRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your webservice URL here"]];

[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

where you can implement delegate methods

Answer (score 0):

In your Button Method

```
 //yourURL is the webservice URL
 [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadDataFromWebservice:) withObject:yourURL];

-(void) loadDataFromWebservice : (NSString *)strUrl
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strUrl];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl];
    //Do your manipulations with data

    //If you want to update any UI with the webservice data 
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(assignDataViews:) withObject:responseObject waitUntilDone:YES];
    [pool release];
}

//Return any object which you are comfortable with. I returned NSArray
-(void)assignDataViews : (NSArray *) yourObject
{
     //Do all your UI changes here
}
```